# Where do I put the require code for autoloader.php?

Tags: drupal-7, google-api-php-client, drupal-feeds

I am clearly new at this. But I'm having trouble installing the google-api-php-client library. On Google's documentation page, it says:

After obtaining the files, include the autloader. If you used Composer, your require statement will look like this:

```
require_once '/path/to/your-project/vendor/autoload.php';
```

If you downloaded the package separately, your require statement will look like this:

```
require_once '/path/to/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I know this is probably an simple answer, but where in my project am I supposed to put the code?

Is there a file within the google-api-php-client directory that I am supposed to put this line in? Or do I need to place this line directly into my website's html in order for the library to properly install?

I am using Drupal 7 and I installed the library with composer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have 3 files, **mail.php**, **calendar.php** and **drive.php**. With **mail.php**, I run a script that sends emails from my google account, with **calendar.php** I run a script that inserts a new event in my calendar and with **drive.php** I run a script that uploads a file to my drive. *Each one* of those files will need the `require_once '/path/to/your-project/vendor/autoload.php';` after `<?php`. For example:

```
<?php session_start();

require_once '/path/to/your-project/vendor/autoload.php';

//run the rest of your script that requires interacting with google services.
```

Please take a look at the example in the documentation located [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and the example [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-file-upload.php)